# Consider the extension $K_i$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ by adjoining $(p^i-1)^{th}$ roots of $\pi$

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let us consider the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $\pi$ be the uniformizer of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Consider the extension $K_i$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ by adjoining  $(p^i-1)^{th}$ roots of $\pi$, i.e., $K_i=\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[p^i-1]{\pi})$ such that $K_i \subseteq K_{i+1}$. Then take union $K=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} K_i$. Then obviously $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, probably "infinite extension".

**My question-**

What kind of extension $K$ is ?

Is it algebraic extension extension ?

Is it maximal unramified or maximal abelian extension ?

I know that for any algebraic extension $F$, it can be written as a union of finite subextensions i.e., $F=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} K_i$ such that $[K_i: \mathbb{Q}_p]< \infty$ and $K_i \subseteq K_{i+1}$.

Help me with the above three questions.

Comment: I do not know what kinds of answers you have in mind for the first one. If $x \in K$, then $x \in K_i$ for some $i$. So, it is an algebraic extension (over $Q_p$). For your 3rd question, if you are asking that $Z_p \subset \bar{Z_p}^K$ is unramified, then the answer is no. I am not familiar with the definitions of a maximal ramified or maximal abelian extension. Maybe definitions or references may be helpful.

Comment: @Youngsu, the first answer is what I was thinking. Thanks for that. I understood that it is an algebraic extension. Is it finite extension or infinite extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, write $n_i=p^i -1$ (since you don't give your motivations, I can't see the reason for the explicit form of $n_i$). Introduce $K_i=\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt [n_i] \pi)$ and $F= \cup K_i$. *Preliminary remark*: there is no inclusion $K_i \subset K_{i+1}$ . Actually, the polynomial $X^{n_i} -\pi$ is Eisenstein, so $[K_i : \mathbf Q_p]=n_i$, but a priori $n_i$ does *not* divide $n_{i+1}$. So you can make sense only by considering the compositum $F$ of all the $K_i$'s. You ask 3 questions about $F$ :

1) Is $F/\mathbf Q_p$ an algebraic extension ? Sure, by construction it is an infinite algebraic extension.

2) Is it maximal unramified ? No, it isn't even unramified, since any $K_i$ is totally ramified (Eisenstein).

3) Is it maximal abelian ? No, by construction it is not even galois ! To get a galois extension over $\mathbf Q_p$, introduce the compositum $K$ of $F$ and of all the cyclotomic fields $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt [n_i] 1)$. But $K$ will not be abelian since it has subextensions (all the $K_i$'s) which are not galois over $\mathbf Q_p$.

Comment: I need the corresponding Galois group to be cyclic. If I take $\sqrt[p^i-1]{\pi}$-th roots with $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then the Galois group $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p( \sqrt[p^i-1]{\pi})/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is cyclic of order $p^i-1$. That is my motivation. Do your finite extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[n_i]{\pi})$ give us cyclic Galois group ?

Comment: The first extension that you mention is galois iff  $Q_p$ contains the $(p^i - 1)$-th roots of unity. Going to the residual field  $F_p$, this appears impossible : $F_p$ is finite, wereas the images of the previous roots are distinct.